# Data Duplicating

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have pulled data from a database to be shown on a webpage; however when I enter four or more times the data is duplicate. That is it show four different set of the same items entered and the database; it doesn't show like. In debugging I recognize that this code line  items.Add(item); keeps repeating but unsure what to change to. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiL5v.png) that's my output at the moment. My desired moment for the item on a requisition to shown one time. This is the result of executing the procedure[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9jQ0.png); there four items entered on the req number was returned; however if you looked at this picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChZTp.png) you will see that it is there 12 times which means it multiply 3 times.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult RequisitionList(List<Requisition> postingObj)
    {
        IssueDAO dbObj = new IssueDAO(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TWCL_OPERATIONSConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        List<string> reqNumbers = new List<string>();

        if (postingObj == null)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "There is no transaction to be posted";
            return View(dbObj.GetAllRequest());
        }

        foreach (var item in postingObj)
        {
            if (item.postTrnx)
            {
                reqNumbers.Add(item.reqNumber);
            }
        }
        if (reqNumbers.Count == 0)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Please select at least one request.";
            return View(dbObj.GetAllRequest());
        }

        dbObj.SetRequisitionStatus0(reqNumbers);
        ViewBag.Message = "Approval Successful!";
        return View(dbObj.GetAllRequest());
    }

 public ActionResult RequisitionList()
    {
        List<Requisition> issuesListOb = new List<Requisition>();
        IssueDAO dbObj = new IssueDAO();
        dbObj.connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TWCL_OPERATIONSConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        issuesListOb = dbObj.GetAllRequest();

        return View(issuesListOb);
    }
```

**View**

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div>

        <hr />

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                @*<input type="submit" value="Issue" name="Issue" class="btn btn-default" />*@
                @*<input type="submit" value="Search" name="Search" class="btn btn-default" />*@

            </div>
        </div>



        <table id="data">

            <thead>

                <tr>
                    <th class="col-lg-1">@Html.CheckBox("TheOneCheckBoxToRuleThemAll")Select All</th>
                    <th class="col-lg-1 ">Date</th>
                    <th class="col-lg-1 ">Requisition Number</th>
                    <th class="col-lg-1 ">Expense Account</th>
                    <th class="col-lg-1">Requestor</th>
                    <th class="col-lg-1">Department</th>
                    <th class="col-lg-1">LoggedinAs</th>
                    <th class="col-lg-1 ">Item Number</th>
                    <th class="col-lg-1 ">Description</th>
                    <th class="col-sm-1">Quantity</th>
                    <th class="col-sm-1 ">UOM</th>

                    </tr>

            <tbody>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
                {
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].reqNumber)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].department)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].department)


                    @*<tr>
                        <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].postTrnx, new { @class = "checkGroup1" })</td>
                        <td class="label">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].reqNumber)
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].reqDate)


                        </td>
                    </tr>*@
                    foreach (var item in Model[i].items)
                    {
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => item.description)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => item.expense_account)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => item.itemNumber)
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].postTrnx, new { @class = "checkGroup1" })</td>
                            <td class="col-lg-1 tabledata" >@item.requisition.reqDate</td>
                            <td class="col-lg-1 tabledata" >@item.requisition.reqNumber</td>
                            <td class="col-lg-1 tabledata">@item.expense_account.account_desc</td>
                            <td class="col-lg-1 tabledata">@item.employeeDetails.employeeNum</td>
                            <td class="col-lg-1 tabledata">@item.employeeDetails.department</td>
                            <td class="col-lg-1 tabledata">@item.employeeDetails.LoggedInUserName</td>
                            <td class="col-lg-1 tabledata">@item.itemNumber</td>
                            <td class="col-lg-1 tabledata">@item.description</td>
                            <td class="col-sm-1 tabledata">@item.quantity</td>
                            <td class="col-sm-1 tabledata">@item.selecteduomtext </td>

                            @*<td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = @item.lineNum, name = Model[i].reqNumber })</td>*@
                        </tr>

                    }

                }
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <br /><br /><br

   public List<Requisition> GetAllRequest()
{
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("getallrequests", connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                List<Requisition> request = new List<Requisition>();

                SqlDataReader rdrObj;

                connection.Open();
                rdrObj = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (rdrObj.Read())
                {
                    Requisition requisition = new Requisition();

                    requisition.reqNumber = rdrObj.GetString(0);
                    requisition.reqDate = rdrObj.GetDateTime(1);



                    requisition.items = getRequestItemByRquisition(rdrObj.GetString(4));
                   request.Add(requisition);
                }

                rdrObj.Close();

                return request;
            }
        }
}

public List<Item> getRequestItemByRquisition(string Req_No)
{
        List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
        SqlConnection TWCLOPConnect = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ToString());

        SqlCommand itemscommand = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader itemRdr;

        itemscommand.CommandText = "requisition_sp_getItemNum ";
        itemscommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        itemscommand.Connection = TWCLOPConnect;
        itemscommand.Parameters.Add("@Req_No", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Req_No;

        try
        {
            TWCLOPConnect.Open();
            itemRdr = itemscommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (itemRdr.Read())
            {
                Item item = new Item();
                item.itemNumber = itemRdr.GetString(0);
                item.description = itemRdr.GetString(1);
                item.price = Convert.ToDouble(itemRdr[3]);
                item.quantity = Convert.ToDouble(itemRdr[4]);
                item.expense_account.index = itemRdr.GetInt32(5);
                item.expense_account.account_desc = itemRdr.GetString(6);

                item.selecteduomtext = itemRdr.GetString(8);
                items.Add(item);
            }

            itemRdr.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            TWCLOPConnect.Close();
        }

        return items;
}
```

Comment: could do with some sample rows from the database and then expected vs actual output. Are you sure it's simply not that the same data is repeated multiple times in the database?

Comment: I did check the database to see and the results is not repeating multiple times

Comment: so it would be something in the code

Comment: This is all controller-side. Problem might be View-related. Show some code lines from View where yo udisplay the results.

Comment: ok i have updated the question

Comment: Where's your controller action method? What's the Model class in your view? We can see some functions which presumably help to build your model, but not the model itself, or how you return data to the view.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Hey @ADyson I still can't see why I'm getting a duplicate of data

Comment: You've shown two controller actions. Just to confirm, is it a problem within (or within code called from) `public ActionResult RequisitionList()` which we are talking about here? And am I to understand that `dbObj.GetAllRequest();` would call the method you've shown as `public List<Requisition> GetAllRequest()`? It's not clear what class that method belongs to.

Comment: And lastly as I requested right at the beginning we still need to see a sample of your data, your actual output currently, and your desired output. Your description of exactly what is being duplicated is a little bit vague.

Comment: i've posted a picture maybe that will help a little better

Comment: The problem lies here within this function List<Item> getRequestItemByRquisition

Comment: yes...but that wasn't what I asked. Which of the two controller actions are you using when this error occurs? Both of them call that function (I assume, because you also didn't answer my other question). Also the picture is a start but 1) It's hard to see which column name goes with which column, 2) you still haven't said which of those rows you consider to be duplicates, and of which other row they are a duplicate, 3) you still haven't shown what the raw data is from which this comes, 4) you still haven't shown what the output should look like when it's correct. I am not a mind-reader.

Comment: This is the controller i'm using  public ActionResult RequisitionList(List<Requisition> postingObj) all of the rows are duplicating

Comment: executing the procedure shows the correct output which i've shown in the question

Comment: @ADyson is there something wrong with my view or within the controller